YouTube Data API v3 - Are the requests and queries correct?
I made 12 requests to YouTube Data API v3 but the total queries is 9600. Is this correct?
[9600 queries]
[12 requests]
I attempted to upload a video to YouTube via API. I sent the upload request 12 times.
I was expecting the queries to be a number similar to 12 requests.

1,600 * 6 = 9,600 quota shows that 6 YouTube Data API v3 Videos: insert endpoint have been taken into account each costing 1,600 of quota, as you have by default 10,000 of quota, see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota.

Than you @BenjaminLoison
